# Why is the transaction log growing so large?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm performing an update on a DB that is inserting a 15 digit number into 270,000,000 rows of a single column. I think the space required should be around 4GB but it is still running and the transaction log has just hit 180GB.

Comment: what is in your loggs?

Comment: This is a remarkably broad question.  What RDBMS are you using?  What's the data type for the column you're updating?  How are you doing the update (e.g. in a loop, by joining, etc)?

Comment: It is SQL2008R2 and just using a simple "update set column1 = column2 where xxx" to copy some data from one column to another.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions have to store *a lot* of information just in case the changes need to be rolled back.
There needs to be a sequential value to know which order the records were updated/inserted.  It needs to store the original value for the column (some RDBMSs might even store the whole row!).  It needs a unique identifier to tie the data back to the row's location.
It has to store so much data because if something catastrophic happens -- like the database crashing -- it needs to be able to return to a *consistent* state.

Yes, 15 digits * 270 mil may come out to 4 GB, but that completely ignores all of the very important metadata required.

If this is a one-off update that doesn't need to be repeated, it may be faster to simply recreate the table with the column updated.  Compared to inserts/updates/deletes, table creates from selects require almost no transaction logging.

Comment: Thanks, it is a large table and the DB is around 4TB so explains why it is getting so large. Not too bothered about space as we have plenty but assume I can just shrink the log after the transaction has completed?

Comment: If this is a one-off update, it may be much faster simply recreating the table with the column updated.  CTAS statements (Create Table As Select) require almost no logging and can be incredibly fast.  You'll need to rebuild any indexes, but it should be much much faster.

Comment: Can't recreate the table as it has around 50x columns, 270million rows and is being updated 24/7. Plus it is linked to other tables and the software vendor would have a tantrum if we messed with it. The DB has an extremely complicated schema they won't share so i don't want to do anything other than update the data within it.

Comment: The log file does not only store your added column, but complete row versions, sometimes even before+afte image.

Comment: That's a bit more worrying as the table with 270 million rows uses 700GB of space so before and after I could be looking at a transaction log of 1.4TB?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, all pages split due to the significant amount of data added (4/180 = 2.2%; might not seem significant but probably pushes many pages over the edge).

Rebuild the clustered index with a fillfactor (probably 90 is enough). Then, you will not have any page splits when updating.

If this does not help we need to dig deeper.

In any case there will be significant log growth and it will be bigger than 4GB for sure. 180 sounds too much. That sounds like whole pages are stored.